# I use SpeechRecoginition in google cloud client library PHP, is streaming possible?

Tags: javascript, php, webrtc, google-cloud-speech, web-mediarecorder

I am using SpeechRecoginition for google cloud client library PHP.

For examples, refer to this [document.](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.126.0/speech/v1/readme)

We have tested and confirmed the normal operation with local files.

But I want to SpeechRecognition by sending a voice file in real time, not a stored file.

I want to pass data to PHP using MediaRecorder js, analyze the voice coming from PHP, and deliver it back to the client.

This is the [document](https://localcoder.org/send-mediarecorder-blobs-to-server-and-build-file-on-backend) I referenced regarding MediaRecord js.

[client.js]

```
var mediaRecorder;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream=>{
        var options = {
            type: 'video',
            mimeType: 'video/webm'
        };
          
            try{
                mediaRecorder.stop()
            }catch(e){}

            mediaRecorder=null;
            let order = 0;
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,options);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable =function(e) {

                if(e.data&&e.data.size>0) {
                    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data); 
                    reader.onloadend = async function(event) {
                        let arrayBuffer = reader.result;   
                        let uint8View = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                        let response = await fetch('server.php', {
                            method: 'POST',                 
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                chunk: uint8View,
                                order: order
                            })                  
                        });
                        order += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            mediaRecorder.start(250);
    })
```

[server.php]

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\RecognitionConfig;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\StreamingRecognitionConfig;

$speechClient = new Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\SpeechClient();

try {
    $recognitionConfig = new RecognitionConfig();
    $recognitionConfig->setEncoding(AudioEncoding::FLAC);
    $recognitionConfig->setSampleRateHertz(44100);
    $recognitionConfig->setLanguageCode('ko-KR');
    $config = new StreamingRecognitionConfig();
    $config->setConfig($recognitionConfig);

    //$audioResource = fopen('localfile path', 'r'); //original
    
    //receive DATA
    $chunk = $_POST['chunk'];
    $binarydata = pack("C*", ...$chunk);
    $audioResource = $binarydata;

    $responses = $speechClient->recognizeAudioStream($config, $audioResource);

    foreach ($responses as $element) {
        //recognition result send client
    }
}  catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I want to receive video data from [client.js] and analyze the audio in real time in [server.php].

SpeechRecogniton is needed for arrayBuffer type data created in mediaRecorder rather than local file analysis.

Please advise.

Comment: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.126.0/speech/v1/speechclient

If you look at the development guide document, the recognizeAudioStream($config, $audio) function $audio parameter says that a byte string is also possible. right?

Comment: I try below code example(node.js socket)

https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-a-web-server-which-receives-a-browser-microphone-stream-and-uses-dialogflow-or-the-speech-62b47499fc71

finish change [client.js] => [server.js]
I hope we gain good result.

Comment: Currently, are you using the PHP or Node.js backend? Does your input include video also, or is it audio only?

Comment: @VishalK At first, I tried from [client.js] to [server.php], but it didn't work, so I changed it from [client.js] to [node.js] and it's in progress. The input includes both audio and video. Any good way?